# PHP, ERROR: could not prepare SQL staement

Tags: php, hosting

I am trying to get a php page that works fine on my local machine to work on my live hosting account but it keeps throwing Error: could not prepare SQL statement.
It's not returning any records to my database, and it's throwing an error.

```
*/
// if the 'id' variable is set in the URL, we know that we need to edit a record
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
        // if the form's submit button is clicked, we need to process the form
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
                // make sure the 'id' in the URL is valid
                if (is_numeric($_POST['id']))
                {
                        // get variables from the URL/form
                        $id = $_POST['id'];
                        $firstname = htmlentities($_POST['firstname'], ENT_QUOTES);
                        $lastname = htmlentities($_POST['lastname'], ENT_QUOTES);

                        // check that firstname and lastname are both not empty
                        if ($firstname == '' || $lastname == '')
                        {
                                // if they are empty, show an error message and display the form
                                $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';
                                renderForm($firstname, $lastname, $error, $id);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                // if everything is fine, update the record in the database
                                if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE players SET firstname = ?, lastname = ?
                                        WHERE id=?"))
                                {
                                        $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $firstname, $lastname, $id);
                                        $stmt->execute();
                                        $stmt->close();
                                }
                                // show an error message if the query has an error
                                else
                                {
                                        echo "ERROR: could not prepare SQL statement.";
                                }
```

Comment: Apart from the fact you've only shared one image, not two, it's not clear how you would expect us to fix your code just from a picture of the screen? Can mechanics fix pictures of cars? See [ask] and how to create a [mre] for more guidance on making your question answerable.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time on stack over flow I have went back and added the source code and the first image I do apologize.

Comment: thank you for pointing me to How to Ask.

Comment: Should I delete this question and repost it correctly later today when I figure out how to ask properly?

Comment: Instead of echoing a generic error, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to find out why the prepare failed. With prepare statements, it's often a misspelling somewhere. If it works on one server and not another, make sure you've copied the database structure correctly

Comment: @ShadDehart no, do not delete questions - instead edit and improve. You need to add error handling (see above comment) to see the reason, readers may be able to guess - but they shouldn’t need to :). You may find the code pattern of “return early” to greatly help simplify your code.

Comment: @AD7six thank you, how do I add the error handling? Plus I am not allowed to add images yet or I would post how the page is supposed to look compared to how It look on my hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

All that was needed, was to reset the password for the database and the page worked perfectly..Thanks to everyone who helped me..